# Is chrome browser on Ubuntu less secure?

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, chromium

Discover credit card site when using Chrome browser on Ubuntu says

> Outdated browsers can expose your computer to security risks. To get the best experience on Discover.com, you may need to update your browser to the latest version and try again.

[Browser check](https://www.discover.com/credit-cards/member-benefits/security-center/protect-account/device-security.html) link on Discovers's web site is claiming I need to update my browser as it's out dated.

I am on Chrome 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04. All service packs up to date.

Is this bias against Ubuntu/linux based browsers or there is genuine security issue?

Comment: when click check browser it says "we can't recognize your browser update your browser or try another". I've had many sites fail to recognize a linux system. 59 is the latest version of chrome. In their supported browser list they do not list linux OS just Windows and Mac. so I think is a "bias".

Answer (score 3):

Chrome is just as secure on Linux as on Windows.

---

The way these checks work is that:

1. Your browser tells which browser, browser version, and operating system you're using (and a few other things)
2. The site's authors decide whether that's good enough

But that doesn't mean that the authors know what they're talking about. For example, according to the page you link to:

> [Windows] Google Chrome 21.0 or newer available at www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Chrome 21.0 isn't secure anymore. It's horribly outdated. Lots of security bugs have been fixed since then.

More importantly, they don't list **any** browsers as secure for Linux, which most likely means that don't want to give an opinion because they don't know much about Linux, which is quite common.